# Installing Mono 2.0 or higher on Debian Lenny (5.0)

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux

I am trying to install the mono 2.6.7 runtime on debian lenny (5.0). The mono project website says that the apt sources list file for installing mono 2.6.7 runtime on debian lenny (5.0) should include the following entry:

deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports main

When I add the above entry to the apt sources list and run apt-get update, I get the following response :

E: Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

I have tried a number of other apt-sources through my online research and they have failed as well.

All I want is to install mono 2.0 or higher runtime on my debian lenny machine. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Subbu

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: When I run apt-get update with the above entry I get the following response on prompt : E: Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Comment: Try `deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main`